# scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix:Matrix extension

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn to do machine learning works.Here are my two variables:

```
>>> matrix
<1397x9576 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 44655 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> type(density)
<type 'list'>
>>> len(density)
1397
```

`matrix` is generated by `TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform()`. I want to extend the variable `matrix` by adding variable `density` as a new column.Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: do you calculate `density` from the same data set that is passed to `TfidfVectorizer`?

Comment: @MaxU Yes.both density and the matrix are generated from the same data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [scipy hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html) to stack the column density with matrix

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
new_matrix = hstack([matrix, density])
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the proper way to add another column to the matrix

```
 from scipy.sparse import hstack
 import numpy as np     
 from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
 density_2 = np.array(density)
 density_3 = csr_matrix(density_2)
 density_4 = density_3.transpose()
 new_matrix = hstack([matrix, density_4])
```

Comment: @Vivek Kumar  a transpose method is needed when adding the column