# Sklearn Decision Tree - using sparse matrix and other features simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I am using Sklearn Decision Tree for some classification and I have two types of data: categorical and continuous. I used `pd.get_dummies` for my categorical values and ended up with over 90 features. Which is, of course, quite a lot.
The thing is that I then iterate over `max_features` parameter to get the best score for my model, and having more than 20 features is too time-consuming. So I thought that Sklearn could use sparse matricies for my categorical features, instead of 70 columns with 0 and 1.

The question is: can Sklearn use a mix of sparse matricies and regular arrays or no? If yes - how do I do that? Currently I get error: `setting an array element with a sequence`

Here is some code to get the idea. `df_with_dummies` is what I currently use, but I hope there is a way to use `df_with_sparse`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

a = np.random.randn(10,3)
b = np.random.random((10,1))
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = "A B C".split())
df['temp'] = b
df['dum1'] = np.where(df.temp < 0.5, 1, 0)
df['dum2'] = np.where(df.temp >= 0.5, 1, 0)
del df['temp']
df_with_dummies = df.copy()

a = df[['dum1', 'dum2']]
dums = csr_matrix(a)
df['dums'] = dums
df_with_sparse = df.copy()
```

Comment: How are you combining the arrays currently before passing them to `DecisionTreeClassifier`. Show the code where this error is occuring. Maybe you can use scipy to join those matrices. See my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49506972/3374996).

Comment: @VivekKumar added code to clear the idea

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
df['dums'] = dums
```

`dums` being a sparse matrix is not correctly handled by the pandas DataFrame and it will be broadcasted to each row. `pandas` does not complain about it, because it thinks of sparse matrix as an non-array object.

That means that each element in the `df['dums']` column will point to the whole sparse matrix `dums`. So essentially, each array element is being set with an array hence the error `setting an array element with a sequence` when it is being processed in scikit-learn estimators.

For that you can do:

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
df_with_sparse = hstack([df[['A', 'B', 'C']].values, dums])
```

Now you can pass this further.